# Wildcards not found

Tags: snakemake

So I'm a little confused about wildcards. I'd like to get a list of input files with an expand function. The files exist and are created by other rules using these "wildcards" - `{output_name} {split_index}`.

I guess only split_index is a "true" wildcard as output_name is defined in another expand in my `rule all`:

```
expand(["results/{output_name}_1/{output_name}_1.bed",
        "results/{output_name}_2/{output_name}_2.bed",
        "results/{output_name}.txt"],
output_name=config["output_name_prefix"])
```

The first two files are made using another rule which outputs the same string I have in my expand here:

```
def get_values(wildcards):
    expand(
        "results/{output_name}_{split_index}/{output_name}_{split_index}.bed",
    output_name=wildcards.output_name, split_index=wildcards.split_index)
```

```
rule merge_file_list:
    input: 
        get_values
    output: 
        "results/{output_name}.txt"
    shell:
        "for s in {input}; do ${{s}} > {output}; done"
```

I get an error that reads :

```
Error:
  AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'split_index'
Wildcards:
  output_name=Homo_sapiens_ch19
```

What is this error even mean I thought output_name is not a wildcard as the docu reads:

[image]

What exactly does snakemake call a Wildcard? I am confusion..

Answer (score 1):

It is a common misconception to feel no difference between wildcards and variables in `expand` function.

Let's start from the `expand` function. It is just a Python function that has no special meaning to Snakemake. It takes a string with variables (or a list of strings), and parameters that specify how to replace these variables with values. It returns a list of strings, and then the Snakemake magic starts. Actually this function may be used in any context where a function can be used, not only in `input`/`output` sections of rules.

Wildcards are more complex and misunderstood concept (and @GiangLe) in his answer provides a good example of WRONG usage. Wildcards make rules a kind of template that can be applied to different files. The meaning of each wildcard starts in the `output` section, where you specify what kind of files the rule can produce. If there is a way to replace each wildcard with values in such a way that the output matches something that Snakemake wants to produce, it considers the rule as a candidate. If so, it remembers the values of the wildcards that were used for this match, and since then these values are specified for other sections of the rule, including `input`.

Prior to explaining the problem with *your* code I need to make a remark that you don't need the `get_values` function, as it significantly complicates your code, is not idiomatic, and is not needed at all. This code:

```py
def get_values(wildcards):
    expand(
        "results/{output_name}_{split_index}/{output_name}_{split_index}.bed",
    output_name=wildcards.output_name, split_index=wildcards.split_index)

rule merge_file_list:
    input: 
        get_values
    output: 
        "results/{output_name}.txt"
```

is functionally equivalent to a simplified one:

```py
rule merge_file_list:
    input: 
        "results/{output_name}_{split_index}/{output_name}_{split_index}.bed"
    output: 
        "results/{output_name}.txt"
```

Now let's consider the simplified version of code and imagine that Snakemake needs to find a way to produce a file `"results/my_favorite_filename.txt"`. It discovers that there is a rule `merge_file_list` that can produce this file if the wildcard `{output_name}` would be substituted with the value `"my_favorite_filename"`. Now it knows this value and is trying to specify the input of this rule: `"results/my_favorite_filename_{split_index}/my_favorite_filename_{split_index}.bed"`. It successfully replaces the wildcard with the value, and then it discovers that the value for the wildcard `{split_index}` is not specified. Note that this value shall come from the `output` section.

There is not enough info in your question to offer you a solution to your *actual* problem. Maybe what you need is to use `{output_name}` as a wildcard and `{split_index}` as a variable in `expand`:

```py
rule merge_file_list:
    input: 
        expand("results/{{output_name}}_{split_index}/{{output_name}}_{split_index}.bed", split_index=["1", "2"])
    output: 
        "results/{output_name}.txt"
```

Now regarding the wrong usage of wildcards given in the answer from @GiangLe:

```py
rule merge_file_list:
    input:
        expand("results/{output_name}_{split_index}/{output_name}_{split_index}.bed", output_name = OUTNAME, split_index = INDEXEND)
    output:
        "results/{output_name}.txt"
```

NEVER EVER DO LIKE THAT! The wildcard `{output_name}` specified in the `output` is not used in the `input` at all! Instead of the actual value of `{output_name}` Snakemake uses hardcoded values from the `OUTNAME` variable, and you would be lucky if that value would match what you expect. That could be true if you have just a single path to create a single final output, but even in this case using Snakemake is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response! Unfortunately i don't think I was clear enough on what i wanted to do. I need the expand function because i want multiple files as an input to a single execution of the rule and the main problem is i don't know how many split_index files there are. I want the expand function to find them all and feed the list to the shell.

Comment: Then you might want to work with either [output directories](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs) (that will contain all your index files), or even with [checkpoint rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution), which allow for data-dependent execution of rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is from your get_value function.

```
OUTNAME=["Homo_sapiens_ch19"]
INDEXEND=["1","2"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/{output_name}.txt", output_name = OUTNAME)


rule create_files:
    output:
        touch("results/{output_name}_{split_index}/{output_name}_{split_index}.bed")

rule merge_file_list:
    input:
        expand("results/{output_name}_{split_index}/{output_name}_{split_index}.bed", output_name = OUTNAME, split_index = INDEXEND)
    output:
        "results/{output_name}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo {input} | sed 's/ /\\n/g' > {output}
        """
```